# belongs_to association returns nil while the has_many works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, belongs-to

I'm using rails on a legacy database (SQL Server). I'm using the gem `composite_primary_keys` also... I'm currently working with two models and the `home_games` association works fine, but the `home_team` association does not.

```
class Game < MyDatabaseModel
  self.table_name = 'Game'
  self.primary_key = 'GameID', 'League'

  belongs_to :home_team, class_name: 'Club', foreign_key: 'ClubKey', primary_key: 'Home_Team'
end

class Club < MyDatabaseModel
  self.table_name = 'Club'
  self.primary_key = 'ClubID', 'Season', 'League'

  has_many :home_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'Home_Team', primary_key: 'ClubKey'
end
```

Now when I do `myClub.home_games` I get back the expected result of an ActiveRecordRelation of records.  However, when I do `myGame.home_team` I get a nil object.  If I do the following call `Club.where(ClubKey: game.Home_Team)` I get the expected result of one record from Club.  Are my associations not set up correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching your `:foreign_key` and `:primary_key` in the `belongs_to` call. These should be the same for both the `belongs_to` and `has_many` calls, since they refer to which foreign key on the "child" table references which primary key on the "parent" table in the relation. In your case:

```
belongs_to :home_team, class_name: 'Club', foreign_key: 'Home_Team', primary_key: 'ClubKey'
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I wasn't aware that's how it worked.